# Good resource for stored procedures

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, resources

I am looking for good resources on Stored Procedures.  Particularly for Microsoft SQL server 2005, but any overall good resources for SQL will do.  These can be books, websites, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [www.simple-talk.com/sql/](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/). Check out their [SQL Server Crib-Sheet Compendium](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/free-ebook-sql-server-crib-sheet-compendium/).

Answer (score 0):

Look for TSQL resources, because SPs are coded in TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

A good advanced guide to T-Sql is "[The Guru's Guide to Transact-SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615762)" by Ken Henderson.  It's becoming kind of a classic.

Comment: I just checked this out and it was written in 2000 - is it still relevant?

Comment: The latest positive reviews of it in Amazon (from 2007) mention its age, but still praise it.  I'm still using it; it's on the bookshelfs of half the developers in our shop.  I'd say it's still relevant, if dated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a good book. Just had a look on sample pages so don't have a deeper idea.

You may download the Ebook as well.

[SQL Server 2000 Stored Procedures Handbook (Expert's Voice)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590592875)